# ExtJS rownumberer in not in order

Tags: extjs, row-number

The `rownumberer` field in not in order rather it extract the value from the field `id` which i had used for `idProperty`. Thus; making un-ordered.

## Model

```
Ext.define('DataModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty : 'id',
    fields : [ 
       { name : 'id', type : 'int' },
       { name : 'openDate', type : 'string' },
       { name : 'comment', type : 'string' }
    ]
});
```

## Store

```
var openDateStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model : 'DataModel',
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : contextPath + 'data.do',
        reader : {
            totalProperty : 'results',
            type : 'json',
            root : 'data'
        }
    },
    autoLoad : false
});
```

## Grid

```
xtype : 'gridpanel', title : 'Open Date(s)', store : openDateStore ,
columns : [
        { xtype : 'rownumberer', text : 'Sn', width : 15 },
        { xtype : 'gridcolumn', dataIndex : 'openDate', text : 'Date'},
        { xtype : 'gridcolumn', dataIndex : 'comment', text : 'Comment'}
]
```

Always; the order is as per the "id" field and which is never ever guranted to come in order.

I tried; removing the `idProperty` but it didnot work.

Where am i wrong please help.

Thanks

Comment: What you want to do? Do you want to order over the `id` column?

Comment: why you are not using sortIfo

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir i want 'rownumberer' to work independently but it uses the value of 'id' field and thus order is not maintained.

Comment: @naresh 'sortInfo' on what? 'rownumberer' or 'grid' i am using Ext JS 4.

Comment: and sorry for the late reply.. what i did is 'xtype : 'rownumberer', text : 'Sn', width : 15,
                      renderer: function (v, p, record, rowIndex) {
                                if (this.rowspan) {
                                    p.cellAttr = 'rowspan="' + this.rowspan + '"';
                                }
                                return rowIndex + 1;
                            }'. but i must say the UI is not as 'rownumberer' does.

Comment: gentlemen; the most funniest thing; is in the above case it is not working but everywhere else it is('rownumberer') working as expected. believe me or not everything is same. but still unable to figure out why?